# mediasoup node server.js error( worker process failed [pid:undefined])

Tags: webrtc, mediasoup

When I build mediasoup environment, come into dir "server". I use the command `node server.js` which results in the following error:

> mediasoup:ERROR:Worker worker process failed [pid:undefined]: spawn /root/mediasoup-demo/server/node_modules/mediasoup/worker/out/Release/mediasoup-worker ENOENT

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VooOw.png)

Comment: same get error and i fix ``npm install mediasoup@3 --save``

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have all the requirements for the installation process https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/mediasoup/installation/